# When synchronising Video and Audio in FCPX, do the settings matter?

Tags: fcpx, apple, compression-data

I'm struggling to get a mental model of how FCPX actually works, in particular the relationship between my actual audio and video files, the representation of them in FCP, and what actually gets exported, via Compressor in my case.

As I understand it, FCPX doesn't make changes to the underlying media. Clips contain references to the underlying media with additional meta data, but manipulating a clip leaves the original audio or video file in tact.

However, when you synchronise a Video clip with an Audio clip, you're presented with this UI...

[image]

There's a lot of options there, and I'm not sure why. However, all I really want to know is wether those setting actually mean anything when I export my project using compressor. For example, if I have 4k footage and I send my project to compressor and export as 4k, but FCPX has a synced clip with a video format of 720p, does that mean compressor will receive a 720p version of the original media that it then upscales to 4k, or will compressor get the original 4k file?

I'm assuming Compressor gets the original 4k media. It seems crazy to do it any other way. Also, those synchronised clips don't seem to exist in my library. But I'm just really confused by why FCPX presents these options when you synchronise audio and video and I suspect it's because I'm lacking some fundamental knowledge that would help me proceed with confidence.

I realise this is potentially a broad question that may be difficult to answer succinctly, but I'd be happy with a link to some part of the documentation or a blog post that you feel sheds some light on this.